# connecting to Neo4j Community edition

Tags: database, neo4j, graph-databases

I installed Neo4j Enterprise edition first and now I'm working with it without any problem . Then I installed community edition and I followed the exact same rules that I followed for installing Enterprise edition . I mean I opened cmd, went to the directory and wrote neo4j.bat install service and then Net start neo4j.
The problem is that I can not connect to the community edition !!
I set different ports for community edition but again I can not connect .
Here :[image]

and another problem is that when I go to the directory through cmd and write net stop neo4j , the enterprise edition get stopped !!! I go to the community edition and the write net stop neo4j but the enterprise edition goes down
thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop Neo4j community edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49607308/how-to-stop-neo4j-community-edition)

Comment: Do you need to have both versions on the same platform? Why not uninstall and then load only the desired one. I'm very happy with Neo4j Desktop which uses Enterprise and has a good GUI for managing the various databases and plug ins.