# How to stop Neo4j community edition

Tags: graph, neo4j, graph-databases

I have installed both Neo4j Community edition and enterprise edition.
The problem is that I can not connect to community edition despite assigning different port on Neo4j.conf
and another problem is that when I go to the Community edition directory and write :Net stop neo4j , The enterprise edition goes down!!! I'm stopping community edition but the enterprise edition stops !!!
What's wrong ??
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem linked to Windows service.

You have installed Neo4j Enterprise as a service with the neo4j install command. This one creates a Windows service with the name `neo4j`. 
If you redo the same with an other Neo4j server, it will not create a new service. In fact I assume is doing nothing because a service with the name `neo4j` already exist.

So when you call `Net stop neo4j`, you are asking to windows to stop the service `neo4j`, not to stop the service where you are with your console.

To start your second server, just go inside its `bin` directory and run this command `neo4j.bat start`, it should start your server.

If your goal is to have multiple instance of Neo4j for some development purpose, I recommend you to use the Desktop version of neo4j.